# Unable to override the connection timeout value in JMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, timeout, load-testing, connection-timeout

I tried to set the deafult connection and response timeout values to 120000 milliseconds (120 seconds) both for the request default and individual requests, but the test still fails if it takes more than 20 seconds. It runs for few threads for say 300, but does not run for more, say 400.

I also tried changing the timeout values in jmeter properties file, but still the results were same

Does anyone know how to change the timeout values? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkENe.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pehjb.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q10EB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's JMeter timeouts, as far as I can see maximum response time is 21 seconds so most probably it's the system under test which has the timeout on its side, some form of logic that terminates connections after 21 seconds.

So check the sever-side settings.

Also given you cannot reproduce it using lower number of threads I would say that the system under test gets overloaded so you can do the following:

1. Check logs for any suspicious entries
2. Ensure that there is enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, Swap, etc. If no better solution is there already you can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)
3. Check database logs in terms of heaviest and [slowest queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html)
4. If there is an [APM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) or a [profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) tool connected to the application look into its output to see what is under the hood of requests which take > 20 seconds.